# libusb interface already claimed

Tags: linux, usb, driver, libusb

I'm writing a device driver for a usb device using libusb.  When I attempt to claim the device I get the error code LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY (-6).  According to the documentation that means that the device has already been claimed ([link](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#ga32fabedf5f13fdecf1cb33acdb19b57a)).

How do I find out which driver/program has claimed the device and more importantly,  how can I, **myself**, claim the device once it's claimed.

Code snippet:

```
r = libusb_claim_interface(handle[0], 0);
if (r < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "libusb_claim_interface error %d\n", r);
    goto out_release;
}
printf("claimed interface\n");
```

Output:

```
libusb_claim_interface error -6
```

Comment: I found this post looking for "_How do I find out which driver/program has claimed the device_", and so I wanted to link this question: [Is there a way to figure out what is using a Linux kernel module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448999/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-what-is-using-a-linux-kernel-module), which I think is relevant, because it says that it is not possible to see which programs claim a driver/module.

Answer (score 18):

Do you call `libusb_detach_kernel_driver()` before `libusb_claim_interface()`?  This may be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is most likely that interface is claimed by another Linux driver. call `libusb_detach_kernel_driver()` and specify the interface number and then you should be able to connect it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `libusb_set_configuration()` before `libusb_claim_interface()`?

This must be called even if there is only one configuration in the descriptor.

Comment: I did try it but got the exact same error back (-6).  Taking a peak at `usb-devices` from the terminal lists `usb-storage` as the driver for the device.  For some reason the device is getting a driver assigned and I haven't been able to prevent this.  I've tried by using udev rules.