# how to know what instances are using a specific loadable kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel-module

`lsmod` can show modules currently loaded and how many instances are using them. Just like the infomation shown below.

```
user@centos7:~$ lsmod | grep fuse
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   85681  1
```

I want to know exactly which instance is using the module because I want to unload the module by killing the process.

I have tried enabling `CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD` option when compiling the kernel and typing `rmmod -f fuse`, but the system just freezes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to figure out what is using a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448999/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-what-is-using-a-linux-kernel-module)

Comment: `fuse` module provides a way for filesystems to use FUSE functionality, so the driver is likely used by some filesystem. Run `mount` and check out the mounts of type `fuse`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for comment and my problem is much easier...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [@tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) 's comment. There's no filesystem using it but when I type `mount -l` it shows

```
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
```

so I typed `sudo umount /sys/fs/fuse/connections`. After that I can unloaded it successfully. The problem I encountered seems much easier than the link you posted.